# Can't load images from file to ios device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, device

I am currently loading in local images to my project. When I run the app on a simulator the images load just fine. But when I run the app on a device the images don't show up.

I've messed around with several forms of loading in documents. `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`, `NSURL`s and such.

Anyway, here is what works for loading the images into the simulator. (the code is in a loop and the images are named "1.jpg", "2.jpg", etc.

```
NSString *pathName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d%@",@"<filePath>", counter, @".jpg"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pathName];
```

I notice that when the app runs on a device, image in nil

Comment: There needs to be a slash (`/`) between the path and the filename.

Comment: Right, that's just an example filepath

Comment: You really should show the code for getting the path. That is probably where your issue is.

Comment: Are you sure you're including the file in the bundle?

Answer (score 0):

You have two things wrong with your code:

1. Don't use the quotation marks.
2. You're not referencing from the App's Main Bundle. This may sound stupid, yes, but try executing this for NSString:

...

```
NSString *pathName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", counter] fileType:@"jpg"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your images are added in **Compile Source under apptarget-> BuildPhases->CompileSources**.

And to get the file path you can use below code

```
NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", counter] fileType:@"jpg"];
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a folder that contains all of these jpgs? I tried linking the folder under Compile Sources, but the images don't seem to copy over. @Malav Soni

Comment: no you can't add the folder directly, but you can import folder and make sure your app is selected in target while importing and then add images to compile sources if they are not already there....